# how to insert multiple record in databse using php

Tags: php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jeetu") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {

    $n = $_POST['name[]'];
    $c = $_POST['contact[]'];
    $a = $_POST['address[]'];
    $count = count($n);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        print_r($n[$i]);
        print_r($c[$i]);
        print_r($a[$i]);        die(); 
        $query = "insert into add (name, contact, value) values ('" . $_POST['name[$i]'] . "'," . $_POST['contact[$i]'] . ",'" . $_POST['address[$i]'] . "')";
        mysqli_query($link, "$query");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and provide more info on what you want to do and where you have reached so far.

Comment: So whats wrong in your Code..? Did you Getting Error ? Notice ?

Comment: `insert into add (name, contact, value) values (?,?,?), (?,?,?), (?,?,?), (?,?,?)` Just keep repeating sets of brackets after values.

Comment: You script is not protected against [sql injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should at least [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a form to input this data into a database there is no way your code will work since you're getting data from one form and not from many forms.

`$count = count($n);` will always return 1 because you are getting one name from the form. It only works if you're reading the data from the database.